# Is there any limits for the Range.Cells.Count?

Tags: vba, range, row, counter

I have a simple row counter.

```
Total = Sheets("support").Range("A1", Sheets("support").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
```

It works perfect until I count more ten thousands rows, because in that case I get this error message:

> Overflow
>   What cause this and how can I count for example more hundred thousands rows?

Comment: how is `total` defined? If it is an `int`, change it to `long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Cells` is redundant, the `.Count` member call can be made directly off the `Range` object returned by the preceding `Range.End` member call.

That said, it depends what `Total` is declared as. If it's an `Integer`, then it only has 16 bits to store a signed integer, which means its upper limit is 32,767 - i.e. `2^15-1`.

```
Dim Total As Integer ' 16-bit
```

Using a `Long` integer would give it 32 bits to do the same, making its upper limit `2^31-1`, which should be more than enough for most uses.

```
Dim Total As Long ' 32-bit
```

If you overflow a `Long`, VBA7 on 64-bit systems gives you `LongLong`, a 64-bit signed integer type that won't overflow until `2^63-1` is busted.

```
Dim Total As LongLong ' 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the CountLarge property instead of Count, i.e.

```
.Cells.CountLarge
```